# How do i see the content of a google forms when it is already closed? Only see the content, dont want to answer

Tags: javascript, html, forms, spoof

I want to see the content of a google forms link but it is already closed. Is there a way just to see it?

i want to somente tell me if it is possible to solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Are you the owner of that form?
You will no longer be able to access or see it if you are not the owner.

Comment: no, im not the owner of the form. Is it impossible to get the content?